# RDP over ssh tunnel using iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

so i want to tunnel an RDP connection through ssh using my iphone-4s. I already know how to tunnel this connection using putty(the ssh client). The only problem is i'm yet to find an SSH client for iOS that allows tunneling(or port forwarding). Please help me find an app that will do what i have described. I am almost positive this can be done with a jail-broken device but until iOS 7 is released, an untethered jailbreak for the iphone-4s is highly unlikely. Please give me the names of the jail-broken apps that can achieve this anyway. Thanks :]

Comment: port forwarding in this situation means sending data on a specific port to a specific ipaddress. look in putty if you have it sitting around your computer under the tunneling tab.

Comment: this is required in tunneling so that the device doing the tunneling can open up a connection on itself. So, if tunneling into RDP is successful it should open port 3389 on localhost of the tunneling machine. then you would connect to localhost:3389 using an RDP-client so that the request is sent to the SSH tunnel then to the SSH server, then to the RDP-server. and vice-versa on the return.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: [this](http://www.zinger-soft.com/iSSH_features.html) looks promising...

Answer (score 2):

iSSH definitely works to create tunnels on a non-jailbroken iOS device, but you can still only keep it backgrounded for 10 minutes or so before it gets killed.

If you jailbreak, however, iSSH is just a luxury (I haven't found a client with a more useful keyboard) because you can just open a terminal and create a local tunnel from the command line all with just free stuff. There's something called AutoSSH in Cydia that is supposed to keep ssh sessions connected. It's not great, but there's not really anything else that does the job. That, combined with ShellScript Launcher, which lets you run scripts from SBSettings, will give you an easy way to start and kill your tunnel.

My StartTunnel script looks something like this:

```
killall autossh
sudo -u mobile autossh -M 3489 -f -g -N -T -L 3389:windowshost:3389 user@myjumphost
```

and the KillTunnel script is simply..

```
killall autossh
```

I use 2X Client and connect to localhost on whatever port I pick for the tunnel. My only complaint there is that the Ctrl key never works for me. Most other free RDP clients either lack the extended keyboard or configurability of resolution/color depth/etc.

Answer (score 0):

iSSH has this capability, and it's a good all-around tool besides; I prefer Prompt for a pure SSH client, but iSSH can't be beat for value.